# Java AddRequestProperty while already connected?

Tags: java, http, cookies, request, urlconnection

Is there a way to use addRequestProperty if you have already connected to the URLConnection?
I need to do this cause I first have to connect to get the headerfields for the first Cookie, but later I have to send that first Cookie in order to get headerfields where a second set-cookie field is defined.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. The HTTP protocol conveys those properties as header items at the beginning of the request data. You'll need multiple requests.